# How to dynamically validate data types in C#?

Tags: c#

So I have a program for this class where I'm supposed to allow the user to select a data type like byte, int, short, long, and etc. And then I am supposed to validate and make sure that the numbers they enter for the math problem aren't outside of the bounds of the data type they selected. Right now I'm using a bunch of if statements for each individual data type, and checking if it's above MaxValue or below MinValue. However, there has to be a better way to do this, right?

My current code is like this (numType is a byte set to the value of a constant when the button is pressed):

```
if(numType = BYTE){
  if(leftNum > byte.MaxValue){
    errorsEncountered = true;
    returnString = returnString + "Left number must not be more than " + 
      byte.MaxValue.ToString() + " for a byte.\n";
  }
  if(leftNum < byte.MinValue){
    errorsEncountered = true;
    returnString = returnString + "Left number must not be less than " + 
      byte.MinValue.ToString() + " for a byte.\n";
  ... (so on and so forth)
}
```

However I'd like to think that you could instead use something like a variable to record the data type and use that instead. So lets say that you have an array of each potential value of numType (1-7 in this case). Would there be a way to do something like this?

```
byte numType = 8; // Will never be returned as this, an error is output for this value immediately.
const byte BYTE = 0;
const byte SHORT = 1;
const byte INT = 2;
const byte LONG = 3;
const byte FLOAT = 4;
const byte DOUBLE = 5;
const byte DECIMAL = 6;
string[] dataTypes = {"byte", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "decimal"};
if(leftNum > dataTypes[numType].MaxValue) {
  errorsEncountered = true;
  returnString = "Left number must not be more than " + 
    dataTypes[numType].MaxValue.ToString() + " for a " + dataTypes[numType] + ".";
}
if(leftNum < dataTypes[numType].MinValue) {
  errorsEncountered = true;
  returnString = "Left number must not be more than " + 
    dataTypes[numType].MinValue.ToString() + " for a " + dataTypes[numType] + ".";
}
```

I know my demonstration is incredibly simplistic but I genuinely don't know how better to describe what I'm trying to do. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Edit: Honestly it seems I'm a bit out of my depth here. I have no clue what most of these solutions are actually doing, and I've come out of this with the impression that I should probably just work on learning the language as a whole.

Comment: i havent tried it , but what if you did Numtype.TryParse, ie Byte.TryParse etc

Comment: The if statement is using `==` in my actual code, it's just in a VM so I can't readily copy in or out of it.

Comment: Also, BYTE is just the name of the constant, so it's just a variable name and not the actual value of numType itself.

Comment: Use an `enum` to represent the type. Create a class that includes a bool flag that describes whether the type is integral or non-integral and both min and max values. You'll need to use long for those values for integral types and double for the non-integral types. Make the test code a member of that class. Then create a dictionary (indexed on the type enum) of all possible instances for the types. This will work reasonably well (but won't work perfectly for the non-integral types).  Sorry, on my phone, otherwise I'd write an answer

Comment: Seems like something you could do with Reflection. Write a method that takes a `Type` object that represents the appropriate numeric type and use Reflection to call the `TryParse` method of that type. You're going to have trouble specifying that a number is outside the allowable bounds of a type because how do you do that for all types? It seems to me that you should just call `TryParse` and then specify the acceptable bounds in both directions if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a dictionary of all the types you want to use with the string you want the user to type in to refer to that type, then use reflection to call `TryParse` and `MinValue`/`MaxValue` if needed.

Something like this:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> aliases = new() {
    { "byte", typeof(byte) },
    { "short" , typeof(short) },
    { "int" , typeof(int) },
    { "long" , typeof(long) },
    { "float" , typeof(float) },
    { "double" , typeof(double) },
    { "decimal" , typeof(decimal) }
};

static void Main() {
    Type type;
    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the type:");
        var selectedType = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        if (!aliases.TryGetValue(selectedType, out type)) {
            Console.WriteLine("You did it wrong");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Type a value:");
        var value = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        // Create an instance of whatever type we're using
        object result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // Get a reference to the TryParse method for this type
        var tryParseMethod = type.GetMethod("TryParse", new[] { typeof(string), type.MakeByRefType() });

        // Call TryParse
        if (tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { value, result }) is bool success && success) {
            Console.WriteLine("You did it right!");
            break;
        } else {
            // TryParse failed, so show the user the min/max values
            var minValueProp = type.GetField("MinValue");
            var maxValueProp = type.GetField("MaxValue");
            Console.WriteLine($"You did it wrong. Enter a value between {minValueProp.GetValue(result)} and {maxValueProp.GetValue(result)}");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Enter the type:
byte
Type a value:
-1
You did it wrong. Enter a value between 0 and 255
Type a value:
1
You did it right!
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of code would be helpful, for instance how `leftNum` and `numType` are declared.

Let's try to help anyway. You can try a polymorphic approach.

It may be overkill, but it's a nice exercise:

- Create an interface, let's say `ITypeValidator`
- Create the implementations of such Interface, i.e. `IntegerValidator : ITypeValidator`
- Have a Dictionary containing your validators and their respective type `Dictionary<byte, ITypeValidator>`
- Initialize your types in your Dictionary.

Sample:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myTypes = GetTypesImplementingInterface();

        byte numType = 2;
        object leftNum = 3;

        var validator = myTypes[numType];
        var result = validator.Validate(leftNum);
    }

    public static Dictionary<byte, ITypeValidator> GetTypesImplementingInterface()
    {
        // Fancy approach would be to use reflection to scan the Assembly 
        // for implementations of our interface and automatically 
        // instantiate and fill in the Dictionary

        return new Dictionary<byte, ITypeValidator>()
        {
            { 2, new IntValidator() }
        };
    }

    public interface ITypeValidator
    {
        byte TypeNumber { get; } // Tip: this helps with the Reflection approach
        ValidationResult Validate(object number);
    }

    public class ValidationResult
    {
        public bool HasError { get; set; }
        public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    }

    public class IntValidator : ITypeValidator
    {
        public byte TypeNumber => 2;

        public ValidationResult Validate(object number)
        {
            // do your things

            return new ValidationResult();
        }
    }
}
```

If your validations are always the same (min and max), you can also think of adding a base class, with abstract Minimum and Maximum properties and a base validation method. So for each type, you just need to implement the TypeNumber, Min and Max values.